# Invite a friend to telegram channel

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

Is it possible to have an “inline button” on a channel that says “invite a friend” that forwards the private channel URL to friends on the channel. The idea is to make the “invitation process” for users to invite their friends much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes . Go to channel and then click on `manage channel` then click on `channel type` and you will see a pop-up that you can select your channel type as `Public Channel` or `Private Channel` .
In the below of the form you can see `Invite link`. So you can copy it and give it to your friends or have an "Join channel" button with that refer to that link.

[Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro#url-buttons) is a link that you can read more about `URL buttons` and here is [API link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options)

These screen shots are also useful :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What I’m saying is - can I take this invite link and hide it behind an “inline button” and then allow a user of the channel to FORWARD the link to a friend without actually seeing it himself?

Comment: Yeap , You can do it :-) That's why I explained about `inline buttons`